# Move column values to hstore in Postgres cannot finish on 15 million rows

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I'm trying this query to move some metadata in a `hstore` attribute

```
UPDATE media_files
SET metadata = hstore (bb)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
    video_bitrate,
    video_codec,
    video_resolution,
    video_fps,
    video_aspect,
    video_container,
    audio_codec,
    audio_bitrate,
    audio_sample_rate
    FROM
    media_files
  ) AS bb
])
```

The table has 15 million records, I left the job running for 15 hours and it didn't finish and I'm not able to keep track since the table seems to be locked out for good during the operation.

Is there something I can do to optimize this?

Comment: It is very likely to be much faster to create a new table like `create table media_files_temp as select <list of media_files columns>, hstore(bb) from media_files` then add any indexes and rename that table to "media_files" (and get rid of the original "media_files" table).

Comment: is there any difference in creating original indexes on the new table before or after?

Comment: Creating *after* is *much* faster

Comment: would you provide a somewhat complete example in an answer so I can try and accept? many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note: this assumes you have the space on your server for two copies of the table + indexes. Should work on PostgreSQL 9.2+

```
CREATE TABLE media_files_temp AS
WITH cte AS 
    (SELECT video_bitrate,
            video_codec,
            video_resolution,
            video_fps,
            video_aspect,
            video_container,
            audio_codec,
            audio_bitrate,
            audio_sample_rate,
            <your default value>::INTEGER as play_count
    FROM media_files mf)
SELECT  cte.*,
        HSTORE('video_bitrate',video_bitrate) || 
        HSTORE('video_codec',video_codec) || 
        HSTORE('video_resolution',video_resolution) || 
        HSTORE('video_fps',video_fps) || 
        HSTORE('video_aspect',video_aspect) || 
        HSTORE('video_container',video_container) || 
        HSTORE('audio_codec',audio_codec) || 
        HSTORE('audio_bitrate',audio_bitrate) || 
        HSTORE('audio_sample_rate',audio_sample_rate)
        as metadata
FROM cte;

[create your indexes]

BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE media_files RENAME TO media_files_orig;
ALTER TABLE media_files_temp RENAME TO media_files;
COMMIT;

-- a new column was requested by the OP
ALTER TABLE media_files ALTER your_new_col SET DEFAULT <something>;

ANALYZE media_files;
```

Comment: what about other columns I have to keep? say 'id', 'title', they shouldn't go as hstore, only the attributes listed. thanks.

Comment: ah, I overlooked that. Hold on, I'll see if I can revise it.

Comment: thanks, I get a `ERROR:  array must have even number of elements`, I'm not sure what is it.

Comment: I've revised it to use `ROW()` instead of a poorly-chosen `ARRAY[]`.

Comment: sorry, removed previous comment, I'd like to ask instead if I can take this occasion to add a new column (int4) in the process with a default.

Comment: @JohnSmith If you get a chance, report back here with how long it took with this method, I'm curious what the time-savings will be.

Comment: I've updated the example to reflect adding the new column, and altering the column to have a default.

Comment: I had many other fields to include, but just the copy to new table took a minute or so, retina mbp ssd 2.3ghz i7. compared to other solutions I tried it's quite good, the time sink now is altering and setting defaults. I don't yet know if a rename takes long or it's instant. thanks.

Comment: mm, I just checked the data in metadata and it's `"f1"=>NULL, "f2"=>NULL, "f3"=>NULL, "f4"=>NULL, "f5"=>NULL, "f6"=>NULL, "f7"=>NULL, "f8"=>NULL, "f9"=>NULL`

Comment: Rename is instant, barring locking. I've updated the example to try show proper key names. There could be other ways to do it, but I can't think of any off-hand.

Comment: thanks, columns are now showing. adding `play_count::INTEGER as play_count` did error with `column "play_count" does not exist`.

Comment: I've modified my example slightly to indicate you should supply a value for the "play_count" column.

Answer (score 1):

A useful answer has already been accepted, but there's something important to point out to future readers.

Your original query had a self-join with no constraining criteria. So - your 15 million row table was receiving 225 trillion updates.